# How can I lowercase the template field in the regular expression extractor in the post processor

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing

I using jmeter for testing my site and created a [regular expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiAYM.jpg) with regex:

lang="(.+?)"

The html body contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl-NL" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

The returned value in regular expression extractor is nl-NL

I'm trying to lowercase the variable to nl-nl and use a variable ${language} in my next https requests.

Any tips?

Comment: Try `${__javaScript(${language}.toLowerCase())}`

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter, you can use scripting functions: jexl, jexl2, BeanShell and JavaScript. See the [JMeter docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> A function call looks like this:
>   
>   `${__functionName(var1,var2,var3)}`
>   
>   Where `__functionName` matches the name of a function.

I suggest using the [JS scripting option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) since it is simple and does not require specific initialization:

> The javaScript function executes a piece of JavaScript (not Java!) code and returns its value

In JS, to turn a string to lower case, use `toLowerCase()` method:

```
${__javaScript(${language}.toLowerCase())}
```